# how to write one regular express for the word cpp or h?

Tags: regex

how to write  one  regular  express  for cpp  or  h?  I  want  to match  the  word  cpp  or  h?

Comment: ... so what's wrong with `cpp|h`?

Comment: it  seems match  cpp  or  cph ,not  cpp or  h

Comment: Which regex engine are you using? That doesn't seem right. In any case, just use parentheses: `(cpp)|(h)`

Comment: should   it   be  add  ()?

Answer (score 0):

Use a non-capturing group,

```
(?:cpp|h)
```

Add word boundaries inorder to match `cpp` or `h` present just before and after to a non-word character.

```
\b(?:cpp|h)\b
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/33)

Comment: does  it  match  cpp  or  cph only?

Comment: it matches `cpp` or `h`, not `cph`

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** validate that a string is *exactly* `cpp` or `h`.

For this, use:

```
^h|cpp$
```

**Explanation**

- The reason why `cpp|h` "matches" `cph` is that the engine is able to match the `h` in `cph`. If you inspect whether a match is found, it will return True.
- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `h|cpp` matches `h` OR (`|`) `cpp`
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

**Option 2:** match `h` or `cpp` as independent words within text

For this, use:

```
\b(?:h|cpp)\b
```

which is essentially the same as the second option in [Avinash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24818194/1078583).